# FFMPEG video to image batch conversion

Tags: image, video, batch-file, ffmpeg

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set EXE_FILE=E:\ffmpeg.exe 
set INPUT_PATH=C:\folder\ 
set OUTPUT_PATH=C:\Images\ 
set COUNT=0 
for %%F in (*) do %EXE_FILE% -i %INPUT_PATH% %OUTPUT_PATH%/%%F.jpg
popd
```

I want to save 1 sec videos to jpg images with this code. This doesnt work. Any solutions?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 0):

`INPUT_PATH` should be a video file, rather than a directory. You need to iterate through the input videos instead of iterating through the output images. ffmpeg will output all the images by itself (without you iterating through them, ie with a single command). Look at [this guide](http://pr0gr4mm3r.com/linux/convert-video-to-images-and-back-using-ffmpeg/) for help. Here is an example from that guide:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mpg -r 1 -f image2 ffmpeg_temp/%05d.png
```

So what you're really doing in your script is you are making the number of digits in the name of the output images more and more.

`%05.png` will make image file names look like "00001.png", and `%03.png` will look like "001.png", etc.

But what you want is to go through the input files, so iterate through for example "video1.mp4", "video2.mp4", etc.

Comment: @Adey ffmpeg will only read the video files, and will not write anything to them. As for the output files, since they will be generated, then there are no file names to preserve. You specify what the file names should be.

Comment: @Adey Ahh, I just got what you meant. Since you already have the input file name (you have to have it to use the command), you can use it in the output name as well, eg something like `%input_file%%05.jpg`. Also, any particular reason you're using jpegs? I'd use tga files instead to preserve the video's quality.

Comment: @Adey I don't know. I don't even know that you can. But my suggestion above was that you iterate through the videos one by one in the for loop. But perhaps you can try something like `*.mp4` instead.

Comment: If the frame rate we specify is less than the frame rate of the video we are breaking down, does ffmpeg break up the video merging consecutive frames or does it chose frames at random?

Comment: Sorry, @nette, I just don't know how it lowers the frame rate.

Comment: How do you use the natural framerate of the video? So it's not inventing filler frames?

Answer (score 0):

```
   IF EXIST %~d1%~p1%~n1.jpg GOTO exit
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set EXE_FILE=E:\ffmpeg.exe 
set OUTPUT_PATH=E:\Glasgow\Test 
set COUNT=0 
for %%F in (*.avi) do %EXE_FILE% -i %~d1%~p1%~n1.avi -r 1 -vframes 1 -ss 00:00:01 -f image2 -y %~d1%~p1%~n1.jpeg
popd
```